# Trying to use RPi camera and turn on LED by telegram bot. Cannot get LED to work

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I've been unable to get the LED function to work by other ways as well. LED on RPi works by using other code.

```py
def handle(msg):
    global telegramText
    global chat_id
  
    chat_id = msg['chat']['id']
    telegramText = msg['text']
  
    print('Message received from ' + str(chat_id))
  
    if telegramText == '/ready':
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'Camera activated')
    while True:
        main() and LED()
def LED():

    global telegramText
    global chat_id

    if telegramText == '/ledon':
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id,'Turning lights on')
        print('Turning lights on')
        sleep(2)
        GPIO.output(24,1)

    elif telegramText == 'ledoff':
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id,'Turning lights off')
        print('Turning lights off')
        sleep(2)
        GPIO.output(24,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice that there is probably a "/" missing in the elif statement of "ledoff"?

> 'ledoff' --> '/ledoff':

For turn off a pin you need a "0" as the second parameter of your function.

> GPIO.output(24,1) --> GPIO.output(24,0)

Could you please add your main function to this issue, because it is difficult to understand your code when the main function is missing. Moreover it seems that you call and endless recursion with

> while True:
>
> ```
>     main() and LED()
> ```